# SQL to remove rows that have timestamps "too close" to a prior timestamp

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table (snowflake) with rows ordered by time stamp. I'd like to select the first row within a timestamp window, and then "shift" the window to the first row outside of the window, and use that (new) row as the baseline for the next set. Essentially, I want to remove rows that are too close to the prior row, where "too close" is some value like 5 minutes.

Examples (time_stamp is the column, the other columns are annotations as I work through this):

```
window = 5 (remove < 5) 

| time_stamp | remove | is_starter | delta from starter |
|------------+--------+------------+--------------------|
|          1 | false  | true       |                  0 |
|          2 | true   | false      |                  1 |
|          3 | true   | false      |                  2 |
|          5 | true   | false      |                  4 |
|          6 | false  | true       |                  5 |
|          8 | true   | false      |                  2 |
|         12 | false  | true       |                  6 |
|         13 | true   | false      |                  1 |
|         14 | true   | false      |                  2 |
|         17 | false  | true       |                  5 |
|            |        |            |                    |

resulting sequence: 1,6,12,17

window = 3
| time_stamp | remove | is_starter | delta from starter |
|------------+--------+------------+--------------------|
|          1 | false  | true       |                  0 |
|          2 | true   | false      |                  1 |
|          3 | true   | false      |                  2 |
|          5 | false  | true       |                  4 |
|          6 | true   | false      |                  1 |
|          8 | false  | true       |                  3 |
|         12 | false  | true       |                  4 |
|         13 | true   | false      |                  1 |
|         14 | true   | false      |                  2 |
|         17 | false  | true       |                  5 |
|            |        |            |                    |

resulting sequence: 1,5,8,12,17
```

I can do this with loops in R or Python (or many other languages), but I'd like to have SQL server do it. My SQL skills just aren't quite up to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @t table (
    time_stamp int
);

declare
    @window int = 5;

insert @t values (1),(2),(3),(5),(6),(8),(12),(13),(14),(17);

with data as (
    select
        *
        ,dense_rank() over (partition by (time_stamp - 1) / @window order by time_stamp) as WindowOrder
    from @t
)
select
    time_stamp
from data
where WindowOrder = 1
order by time_stamp;
```

Note that the result for @window = 3 (1,5,8,12,13,17) differs from your resulting sequence: (1,5,8,12,17) as 13 should also be included.

Comment: Thank you. I think that the 13 should not be included. "12" is the start of a new window, and "13-12" is less than the threshold.

I'll poke at this answer as it likely points me in the right direction. thank you again